# Threads not running in Marshmallow devices

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, activity-finish, htc-android

I've developed one location based app which uses Google Maps API and GPS. In my app I've used `finish()` and `finishAffinity()`in certain methods to close the app.

It is working fine with all the mobiles except the *HTC One M8* (Marshmallow). In that mobile, the app is not closing at any instant and I used a separate thread for the closing activity to be done. I don't know what the problem is.. It is happening only on Marshmallow devices.

My code  (after `onCreate()`):

```
public void onGpsClick(View v) {
    Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    Log.v(TAG, "onClick");


    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locationListener);

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Error: Try after some time ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notification.setAutoCancel(true);


            finishAffinity();
        }
    });
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (Glast == 11) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your are near by..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Timeout.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, 15000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used in my apps like this ;

```
getMyActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Fuat.Let me try this too.